# SCSS structure question, relating to child where parent changes

Tags: sass, parent-child

As an example I have some html as follows:

```
<body id="app_A">
<p>Hello World 1</p>
</body>
```

I want to color the text in `<p>` blue, so I was thinking I could set up my SCSS file as follows:

```
$blue: #00205C;
#app_A{
  p {
     color: $blue;
  }
}
```

However the body id will change from page to page in my website such as:

```
<body id="app_B">
<p>Hello World 2</p>
</body>
```

or

```
<body id="app_C">
<p>Hello World 3</p>
</body>
```

In addition to the `<p>` there will be a number of other items I wish to color code depending on the body id, but I can see the following method getting quite long and cumbersome to maintain even using SCSS:

```
$blue: #00205C;
$red: #FF0000;
$green: #00FF0F;
#app_A{
  p {
     color: $blue;
  }
}
#app_B{
  p {
     color: $red;
  }
}
#app_C{
  p {
     color: $green;
  }
}
```

What would be the best method to set up my SCSS to set child items (`<p>`) where the parent changes `<body id="{changing id}">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I could do this by using the @each functionality:

```
$blue: #00205C;
$red: #FF0000;
$green: #00FF0F;
$apps:
  "#app_A" $blue,
  "#app_B" $red,
  "#app_C" $green;

@each $app, $color in $apps {
    #{$app} {
        p {
            color: $color;
        }   
    } 
}
```

For the other items I wish to color code I can just add these under the `p{}` element.